# JBoss EAP 6.x understand the deployment phase - ResourceAdapters, EJB, jar, war

Tags: deployment, ejb, jboss7.x, jboss-eap-6

In JBoss, how is the sequence of the *deployment phase*? What is the order of object being instantiated and available to use? 
Considering an enterprise application (*.ear), inspecting all deployment log (server.log) the deployment phase looks like:

1. All **libs** are deployed - .class files are loaded and available;
2. All ***.jar** modules are deployed - .class files are loaded and available;
3. If some ***.jar** is an **EJB Jar**, through the configuration files (Ex. ejb-jar.xml) or annotations, the JNDI tree is created;
4. If some ***.jar** has a persistence.xml file configuration, all entity and link to datasources are loaded;
5. All ***.war** modules start the deploy phase;
6. Through configuration files (web.xml), listeners and context-root are loaded and eventually security aspects.
7. **Ear** deployed successful.

Questions:

- *What about the resource adapters modules, the PersistenceContext and the EJB Pool?*
- *When a persistence.xml is found, does a connection to the data-source and so to the DB pool start?*
- *Since the datasource (DB) is configured in the `standalone.xml` or `domain.xml`, when happens the first connection to the DB pool? When I inject the PersistenceContext and use the EntityManager?*
- *When the EJB pool is loaded and available to use?*
- *Is correct to say that during the EJB jar deploy, the JNDI tree is created and then available?*
- *When an EJB is discovered, it's loaded inside the pool (as reference to inject/lookup)?*

When a .war module is deployed and ready, even if the full deploy of the .ear is not completed yet, possibly servlet or listener are started from the container.

- *What happens if some of this objects (listener, servlet) try to use EJBs or PersistenceContext or other objects? Are those objects available?*
- *Is it possible to have deadlock problem and hang the deployment thread/phase?*

Answer (score 6):

- It is possible to [control the deployment order](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-deploy/configuring-jboss-as-7-deployment-order) of jars and wars in application.xml using `<initialize-in-order>true</initialize-in-order>`
- The [lifecycle of the resource adapters](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gipgl.html) is controlled by the [connector architecture](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=322)
- The [lifecycle of Container-Managed Entity Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bnbqy/index.html) are managed by JBoss. Assuming you are injecting into an EJB using `@PersistenceContext`, this happens prior to [`@PostConstruct`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giplj.html).
- Singleton EJB initialization order can be defined using `@DependsOn("OtherBean")`
- You can ensure the EJB endpoints are available using the deployment order in the first bullet
- Not sure if it is possible to dead lock - it is far more likely that you will see a JNDI exception

Comment: Thanks for the information and the useful links. You deserve the bounty. I edited my question and added other questions related to the deployment phase and how the container manage the resources.

Answer (score 3):

I will try to address the rest of your questions:

> When a `persistence.xml` is found, does a connection to the data-source
>   and so to the DB pool start?

Yes, that must happen (if no connection already is made), otherwise no table structure (DDL) could be [validated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7438561/hibernate-jpa-not-validating-against-db-schema-on-startup) or be created.

> Since the datasource (DB) is configured in the standalone.xml or
>   domain.xml, when happens the first connection to the DB pool? When I
>   inject the PersistenceContext and use the EntityManager?

The answer to this question is: it depends. If your JDBC Datasource is configured with a minimum pool size `MIN_POOL_SIZE`>0  and has the [`prefill`](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Server_Configuration_Guide/beta500/html/ch13s04s03s01.html) flag set to true, then WildFly will create `MIN_POOL_SIZE` connections to the DB server, without any deployments at all that use that datasource (after changing that flag you will need to disable/enable the datasource). Otherwise on deployment: it is created as many connections as needed (depending on what you do on deployment, but for simple applications a single one), except you have a `MIN_POOL_SIZE`>0 defined and the strict minimum flag is set to true, in which case AT LEAST `MIN_POOL_SIZE` connections will be created.

> When is the EJB pool loaded and available for use?

It is available for use after deploying the EJB submodule, with all its dependencies.

> Is correct to say that during the EJB jar deploy, the JNDI tree is created and then available?

I would formulate that in the following way: After (*not during*) it is checked that all EJBs can be deployed (e.g all their dependencies could be solved), then JNDI entries are created (in the JNDI tree). According to what I noticed, if a single EJB fails, nothing is deployed, which makes me think I am right here.

> [When a .war module is deployed] What happens if some of this objects (listener, servlet) try to use EJBs or `PersistenceContext` or other objects? Are those objects available?

Yes, definitely. We use that feature to execute some init code from a servlet, when the WAR file is deployed (e.g to create some entities with some default values).

> Is it possible to have deadlock problem and hang the deployment thread/phase?

Theoretically yes, practically no (I doubt the guys at RedHat did not think about this).

---

Some tips: if you use MySQL, you can check what connections are made to the server with `show processlist`. Otherwise if you use Linux/Unix, you can check all made connections to your DB server with `netstat`.